# JS Disable Button based on user input

Tags: javascript

I have 2 text inputs on a Form:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form" id="descriptionInput" placeholder="Customer Name"       onkeyup="manage(this)">
</div>

<div class="form">
    <input type="text" class="form" id="contactName" placeholder="Contact Name">
</div>
```

The idea is to enable the submit button only if these 2 fields have any value:
My button:

```
<button type="submit" id="btSubmit" disabled>Add new Customer Entry</button>
```

My enable/disable function:

```
function manage(descriptionInput, contactName) {
    var bt = document.getElementById('btSubmit');
    var custName = document.getElementById('descriptionInput').value.length;
    var contact = document.getElementById('contactName').value.length;
    if (custName > 0 && contact > 0) {
        bt.disabled = false;
    }
    else {
        bt.disabled = true;
    }
}
```

Issue is:
if customer name field has 1 character only + contact has 1 or more characters = doesn't work
if customer name field has 2 characters     + contact has 1 or more characters = it works

Not sure what's happening, any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: That is because the `manage` function is only called on a key up event on the `#descriptionInput` `<input>`

Comment: @Titus you should write an answer if the OP thinks this is helpful

Comment: Inline event handlers like `onkeyup` are [bad practice](/q/11737873/4642212). They’re an [obsolete, cumbersome, and unintuitive](/a/43459991/4642212) way to listen for events. Always [use `addEventListener`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#inline_event_handlers_%E2%80%94_dont_use_these) instead.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the `manage` function is only called when a key up event is triggered on the `#descriptionInput` `<input>`.
To fix that, monitor both inputs for changes, here is an example:

```js
const btSubmit = document.querySelector('#btSubmit');
const descriptionInput = document.querySelector('#descriptionInput');
const contactName = document.querySelector('#contactName');
function manage() {
  btSubmit.disabled = descriptionInput.value.length === 0 || contactName.value.length === 0;
}

descriptionInput.addEventListener('input', manage);
contactName.addEventListener('input', manage);
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form" id="descriptionInput" placeholder="Customer Name">
</div>

<div class="form">
    <input type="text" class="form" id="contactName" placeholder="Contact Name">
</div>

<button type="submit" id="btSubmit" disabled>Add new Customer Entry</button>
```

Here, instead of listening for key up events, I'm listening for `input` events, this is more appropriate because this event is also triggered when you paste something in an input for example.

Also, instead of adding the event listeners inline, I'm adding them in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add the keyup event on the second input.